# How to take a dependency on Excel in .Net for maximum compatibility

Tags: .net, office-interop

One of our clients asked for a "View in Excel" feature in our Windows Forms App. So now we have to take a dependency on Excel. I have several questions about how to correctly reference Excel.

My feature only relies on APIs that have always been offered in Excel so technically Office XP would be fine. I cannot predict which version of Excel my clients will have. It is also possible that Excel will not be installed at all. I have to detect that and simply disable the "View in Excel" feature.

Questions:

What version of the Office Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA) should I take a dependency on for maximum compatibility with all versions of Excel? Should I use the oldest PIAs or the latest ones?

Will it work and is it legal to distribute the PIA dlls as part of my application (in my own application folder), without installing the official "Office PIA Redistributable" package?

How do I detect if Excel is installed? Also, won't loading the assemblies crash when it will not find Office?

Can you think of any other issues that I should consider?

Comment: We could perhaps start from what you want to CODE here..

Comment: The code is not the issue here, I know the code I need and it is very simple. I just want to make sure I take a dependency in a way the will be compatible with any version of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have added a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll, Version 14.0.0.0

[image]

which corresponds to Office 2010.

I am doing some pretty basic stuff, reading/writing to excel and named ranges and adding a reference to this library (and no other versions) works with Excel back to 2003. (I have test beds running XP and Excel 2003)

Comment: Is this forward compatible? I mean, in a few years from now, if someone has office 2015 and installs your app (compiled against 14.0.0.0) will this still work?

Comment: I don't think you can ever answer that definitely as it would depend on what the developers of Office 2015 decide to do. One thing you could try is reference `Interop.Excel` v12.0.0.0 (as above) which is Office 2007 I think and see if that works with Office 2010 (I have not tried this) to give you at least an indication of forward compatibility.